# Getting mouse move events in embedded Elm program in Chromium

Tags: elm

*Note: I am only seeing this behaviour in Chromium.  In Firefox I get the mouse movement signals I expect when I mouse over the Elm app.*

When I "embed" my Elm program instead of "fullscreen" it, it doesn't give me `Mouse.position` signals unless I click and drag the mouse in the div in which it is embedded.  Even when I move my mouse over the div containing the Elm app, I don't get signals unless I click and drag.

My Elm code is copied directly from http://elm-lang.org/examples/mouse-position :

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Mouse

main : Signal Element
main =
  Signal.map show Mouse.position
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id="mousepos" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
<script src="mousepos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mousepos = document.getElementById( "mousepos" );
Elm.embed( Elm.Main, mousepos );
</script>
```

If I click and drag on the div, I see the numbers change, but if I just move my mouse around, they don't change (even if I've clicked once to give the canvas focus).

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit: emphasised I don't see mouse movement even when I move the mouse over the div containing the Elm app.**

**Edit 2: added note that I only see this in Chromium.**

Comment: This may turn out to be a Chromium issue, but for now I logged this issue against Elm: https://github.com/elm-lang/core/issues/490

Comment: I appear to have found something specific to certain versions of Chromium.  I tried a different version and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Mouse.position` only listens to mouse movements on the top level DOM element making up your Elm app.

You can see this by looking at the source code where [`Mouse.position` is tied to the listening event](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/8cbc41773a6f1354c2929d3b09fdb1fb59dd148e/src/Native/Mouse.js#L33). It adds the listener to the Elm app DOM node only, not the whole page. Since you're doing `Elm.embed()`, your node is just the `mousepos` div, not the whole page.

If you want to respond to mouse positions on the entire page, you'll need to make a port which sends in global mouse position signals from Javascript.

Comment: But I don't get mouse movements even when I move the mouse over the Elm app DOM node.  Is there a way to get them then?

Comment: Hmm.  I just tried this in Firefox and it works as I expected.  I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I've verified that it works in Chrome on Windows (v47.0.2526.111). What is your environment setup?

Comment: $ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 47.0.2526.106 Ubuntu 15.04